# escape characters with strtok

Tags: c, strtok

Let's say that I have the following results from an external machine:

```
Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, C=12.34, D=34.67)
```

I want with strtok to get these values so I have the following code which do exactly what I want

```
ptr = strtok(buff, "Value_,=A:B:C:D()");
         i = 0;
       while (ptr != NULL)
         {
          if (i == 0)
             strcat(out1, ptr); 
          if (i == 1)
             strcat(out2, ptr); 
          if (i == 2)
             strcat(out3, ptr); 
          if (i == 4)
             strcat(out4, ptr); 
          if (i == 6)
             strcat(out5, ptr); 
          ptr = strtok(NULL, "Value_,=A:B:C:D()");
          i++;
         }
      printf("Results: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", out1, out2, out3, out4, out5);
```

My question now is, if I have more or less variables as the following examples how can I improve my ptr variable to receive these different values of the variables?

```
Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, C=12.34, D=34.67, E=50.68)
Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, C=12.34, D=34.67, E=43.96, F=12.45)
Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, D=34.67)
```

**UPDATE**

The solution is that I changed

```
ptr = strtok(buff, "Value_,=A:B:C:D()");
```

with a simple

```
ptr = strtok(buff, "Value_,=:()");
```

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: Put them in an array ;)

Comment: BTW, your understanding of how `strtok()` works is wrong. It will tokenize with any of the characters being the delimiter.

Comment: And it will work? Because I think that ptr will return only A,B,C,D values and not E in the first example, only A,B,C,D and not E,F in the second etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct datap {
    char *sym;
    char *val;
};

int main(void){
    char *test_rec[] = {
        "Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, C=12.34, D=34.67)",
        "Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, C=12.34, D=34.67, E=50.68)",
        "Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, C=12.34, D=34.67, E=43.96, F=12.45)",
        "Value_1:(A=12.34, B=34.56, D=34.67)"
    };
    int i, j, c, rec_num = sizeof(test_rec)/sizeof(char*);
    char buff[1024],* p;
    struct datap out[26];

    for(i=0; i<rec_num;++i){
        strcpy(buff, test_rec[i]);
        strtok(buff, "(");//skip to '('
        for(c=0;NULL!=(p=strtok(NULL, " ="))/* && c < 26*/;++c){
            out[c].sym = p;
            out[c].val = strtok(NULL, ", )");
        }
        printf("Results: ");
        for(j = 0; j < c; ++j){
            printf("%s=%s", out[j].sym, out[j].val);
            if(j < c - 1)
                printf(", ");
            else
                printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a key/value pair, but strtok will only give you the value. To do what you want, you need the key (A,B,C,D etc).

You can't do this with strtok.

How about using sscanf (psuedo):

```
find the opening bracket

do
  sscanf(bufPos, "%c=%f,%n", &key, &value, &skip);
  bufPos+=skip
repeat until buf[bufPos]==')';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the format is rather fixed, you can use a slightly simpler approach to get all keys/values. How you want to store them is up to you, but a more dynamic approach than fixed variable names may be a good thing.

```c
const char* pattern = ",) ";

char* ptr = buff + 9;                // Skip "Value_1:("
ptr = strtok(ptr, pattern);
do {
  printf("key %c, value %s\n", *ptr, ptr+2);
} while ((ptr = strtok(NULL, pattern)) != NULL && *ptr);

> key A, value 12.34
> key B, value 34.56
> key C, value 12.34
> key D, value 34.67
> key E, value 50.68
```

Answer (score -2):

You should put the elements retuned from strtok in an array. Something as follows:

```
char *ret[MAX_VARS];
ptr = strtok(buff, "Value_,=A:B:C:D()");
i = 0;
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    malloc(ret[i], strlen(ptr) + 1);
    strcpy(ret[i], ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, "Value_,=A:B:C:D()");
    ++ i;
}
int j;
printf("Results: ");
for(j = 0; j < i; ++ j) printf("%s ", ret[i]);
printf("\n);
```